# Is it possible to view database performance information without DBA privilege in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g, roles, privileges, database-administration

Is it possible to have access to the database performance views in Oracle 11g R2 (CPU, RAM, I/O utilization, slowest queries ran, etc.) without having DBA role or privileges ?

As a database developer, I would like to have access to some of this information that the DBAs have.

Thanks,
Stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DBA can grant you SELECT privileges to the V$ performance views. It's good for instance tuning, but not as effective as SQL Trace or ADVISOR privilege for query tuning.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/instance_tune.htm

ADVISOR privilege (less powerful than DBA) would be perfect - with that you can run AWR, ADDM, ASH.

If your DBA is willing to give you access to Oracle Enterprise Manager along with ADVISOR, that would also allow you to do real-time SQL Monitoring.

Comment: thank you. I hope my DBA is willing to give me access to these privileges.